# Update all dates to a specific year - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following date data in an oracle table date field:

```
3/5/2007
6/3/2008
1/12/2011
```

I would like to update all the records year portion only to 2020.  So the output would be:

```
3/5/2020
6/3/2020
1/12/2020
```

I tried the following but this only updates if all the source years had the same year and would not work in my case:

```
update my_table
set datefield = datefield + INTERVAL '2' YEAR
```

I would like to have some type of update statement that works this way (This example does not work):

```
update my_table
set datefield = mon(datefield) + day(datefield) + 2020
```

I researched this issue before posting.  The other answers refer to add_months also which does not seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the correct numbers of years to the input date:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET datefield = ADD_MONTHS(datefield, 12*(2020 - EXTRACT(year FROM datefield)));
```

So in the case of 2007-05-03, the `EXTRACT` calculation above would find 17 as the difference in years, and the correct number of months would then be added to 2003 to bring up the year to 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way - using hard-coded substrings in date format models. I apply this to `sysdate` for illustration, but this will work for any date expression.

```
select sysdate,
       to_date (to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mm-"2020" hh24:mi:ss'),
               'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as same_date_time_in_2020
from   dual;

SYSDATE              SAME_DATE_TIME_IN_2020
-------------------- ----------------------
01-Mar-2021 07:36:25 01-Mar-2020 07:36:25
```

`to_char()` returns the date converted to string, but using the hard-coded value 2020 (enclosed in double-quotes) instead of the year component of the input date. The rest (`to_date()`) is trivial.

Note that with this approach you will run into trouble if the original date is `29-Feb` and the new year is not a leap year. In that case you must explain what the desired handling is. Tim B's answer will work in that case too - it will just change the date to `28-Feb` if the target year is a non-leap year.

Also, if your dates "don't have time component" (meaning, the time component is always midnight, `00:00:00`, as in Oracle dates *always* have time components), you can simplify the formula - leave out the time components in both format models.